Hide Extension-less C++ Complied Executables on Mac CLion
I'm using CLion to practice competitive programming, so each cpp source file is compiled on its own, without using things like CMake. The problem is, on MacOS, the executables have no extension, so I can't hide them in settings using gitignore-like grammar. I hope to hide ALL of the executables in a custom view scope, not add each one manually, as they are so distracting. See this image for what I mean.
I'm currently using the MacOS Catalina(10.15.7), and the latest version of the IDEs.

Scope in CLion is an allowlist. Something like file:*.* should do the trick, same way as your gitignore works. Probably a better solution would be to move your binaries somewhere separate; maybe bin directory or something that can be excluded easily.

Also VSCode has got "Exclude git ignore" option which seems to work with your .gitignore

I've removed the VS Code part of your question from this Q&A. it duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/78514251/11107541, and you should not ask questions like this for multiple IDEs in the same Q&A (too broad).

Use file:*.* in "scopes".
